# Using SSH server and vi editor inside SSH, how do i copy lines of code and paste into notepad

Tags: ssh, copy, vi, paste, notepad

So I have to use SSH for my computational physics course, and with that we have to use VI editor. I'm coding in fortran 77 because that's the only language I have been taught through this course, but my professor has focused mainly on the physics portion and very little on the coding.

The code that I have written stores 400,001 lines of data into a data.dat file.
I need to copy those 400,001 lines of data into an excel file so that I can make a graph.

The problem I am having is when highlighting the text manually, selecting the select all option, or the select screen option, I am only able to select about 200 lines of code and they usually repeat themselves.

I've seen several shortcuts but I can't get them to work.
I used :%y* and :%y+ and all it says is E488 trailing character.

I have also tried gg"*yG and gg"+yG and all it says is 400,001 lines yanked but then I cannot paste them into my excel file.

I have run myself ragged working on this code for over a month and I am now so close to turning it in but i really need that data and I really need that graph.

Please help me figure this out, I am literally driving myself insane trying to do this.

Comment: I have no idea what scp is or how to use it. I really don't know anything about fortran, SSH, or vi

Answer (score 2):

You ask the wrong question.
Ask instead - transfer file through ssh - and You will get many possibillities
Here is just one

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles

If you are on a windows machine - just install winscp:
https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Comment: Okay, so I tried that via scp data.txt oxr2932@omega.uta.edu:Desktop but it didn't transfer anything to my desktop? It acted like it was doing something but? I guess its important to mention that I'm using my university's vpn so i'm not technically registered under their host? I'm honestly clueless at this point.

Comment: As I am now sure You are on a windows machine - i edited the answer so You will just use winscp - where you can just browse to the file and transfer it to Your machine.
If you are on mac, it should just be in the file explorer menu.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much! I'm so happy I could honestly cry right now thank you! It had taken nearly an hour just to copy and paste 100,000 lines, you've just made my life so much easier!

Comment: You are welcom - it is my pleasure. been there done that ;-)